# Cannot display sigma char in c#

Tags: c#, encoding, special-characters

I'm trying to display the sigma char within my application. I've debuged down to this :

```
using System;
class Program{
    static void Main(){

        Console.Write("This is Omega: {0}.  And this is Sigma: {1} ",
        "\u03A9", "\u03A3");        
        Console.ReadLine();

    }//end Main
}//end class Program
```

Unfortunately, it displays on my console the following text :

```
'This is Omega: O.  And this is Sigma: S'
```

I know this is related to encoding but I can't manage to find a way to make it work...

Edit : Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() = **fr-CH**

Comment: Are you sure it's not just that the console font is unable to display that character?

Comment: Erm maybe, I tried to write it down in a PDF and this is where I had the problem in the first place. I made a few attempts in a console environment, but I never checked again within my PDF... I'll make a quick test !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the [console's output encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding.aspx). Add this:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

before you attempt to output. And of course you must be using a console font that has glyphs for those characters. My system is configured to use Consolas, and with the `OutputEncoding` specified as above the output is like so:

[image]

Comment: @VMAtm Oh yes it will

Comment: Works fine here. You must have a console font that has the necessary glyphs

Comment: Font ! Interesting, I'll try.... I have a default font for the console tho... Shouldn't we have the same font by default ?

Comment: @AndyM The default – "Raster Fonts" – is common, but is an 8bit font. What others you can switch to (eg. Consolas) depends on your Windows version.

Comment: In the key : HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont, I've found I'm using "Lucida Console" in the Key '0'. I have also Consolas in the key '00'. Which one do you guys have ?

Comment: I've got exactly the same as you in the registry. Which font do you have as your default? That's controlled elsewhere. Click on the system menu of the console window and poke about in there to find out which font is actually being used. After you add the `OutputEncoding` setting, does the output change?

Comment: So, by right-clicking on my console window, properties, I get to the menu "Font" and there, I've foudn that i'm now using Lucida Console.

Comment: oh ! Now it's allright ! I should have used the Polices Raster before ! Switching to Lucida Console AND using your 'Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;' gets the job done ! Wonderful ! Now I have to do the same with my PDF generation....... But thank you a lot !